# Rosserial examples for arduino

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I had problems with the rosserial communication from, the Host (PC,Ubuntu Xenial, ROS Kinetic) to the Device (Arduino Leonardo). The code (HW Input/Output) in the Arduino worked but it did not published or subscribed any topic.

Introduction:
Load Rosserial Hello World Example in Arduino:

```
/*
 * rosserial Publisher Example
 * Prints "hello world!"
 */
//#define USE_USBCON        //<--this is new

#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

std_msgs::String str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);

char hello[13] = "hello world!";

void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter);
}

void loop()
{
  str_msg.data = hello;
  chatter.publish( &str_msg );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Start roscore

```
roscore
```

and start the rosserial communication:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/tACM0
```

After this I had two cases.
First: without any error output

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [1497606946.599728]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1497606946.612089]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
```

here I thought the communication works well, I had a rosnode but no topics

```
    rosnode list 
    /rosout
    /serial_node
    rostopic list 
    /diagnostics
    /rosout
    /rosout_agg
```

Second: with error

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [1497607058.864885]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1497607058.876586]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [1497607075.987434]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

the nodes and topics where the same.

Then I searched for three days for a solution and found this page:
http://answers.ros.org/question/164191/rosserial-arduino-cant-connect-arduino-micro/

The solution for me was the USE_USBCON definition.

```
/*
 * rosserial Publisher Example
 * Prints "hello world!"
 */
#define USE_USBCON        //<--this is new

#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
```

after that I had the desired topic and was able to echo it.

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [1497607701.288109]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1497607701.298771]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [1497607704.031868]: Note: publish buffer size is 512 bytes
[INFO] [1497607704.033017]: Setup publisher on chatter [std_msgs/String]


rosnode list 
/rosout
/serial_node
rostopic list 
/chatter
/diagnostics
/rosout
/rosout_agg
rostopic echo /chatter
data: hello world!
---
data: hello world!
---
```

Conclusion:
For me the problem lies in the rosserial examples which are not up to date and the error messages.

So I have two questions:
Is my conclusion right? And where or whom do I have to write for the updating of the tutorials and editing the error messages?

Best regards
Bukmop

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264025/rosserial-examples-for-arduino/) by [Bukmop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30791/bukmop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The issue you have encountered is because you have used an **Arduino Leonardo** that has a native USB port, which is different that on the Arduino UNO, MEGA...

That's why you have to enable the `USE_USBCON` flag. But it is normal it is not the default.

Maybe, you can edit the tutorials to make it clear that the specific **Leonardo** model needs this flag to be defined.

The tutorials are hosted on a community Wiki so, feel free to create an account and edit them: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial

If you want to change the error message, you can send a pull-request on the Github repository: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial

But note that even if the message is not clear enough, it only state that there is a communication problem. In fact, your Arduino was not send anything on the serial port.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0